# Using Flutter Share to share a locally taken image

Tags: android, ios, flutter, share

I have a simple camera app I made and I want to be able to share the image I take to other people with Share.  However, when I run the following code, it just shares the path to the picture:

```
Share.share(imagePath);
```

Can someone please tell me how to do this?  I think you need to convert the bits somehow.  Thanks!

Here is some more of the code for reference:

```
class DisplayPictureScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imagePath;

  Future<ByteData> getBytesFromFile() async {
  Uint8List bytes = File(imagePath).readAsBytesSync() as Uint8List;
  return ByteData.view(bytes.buffer);
}

  const DisplayPictureScreen({Key key, this.imagePath}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Display the Picture')),
      // The image is stored as a file on the device. Use the `Image.file`
      // constructor with the given path to display the image.
      body: Image.file(File(imagePath)),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {

            print("in print");
            Share.share(imagePath);


            /*
          getBytesFromFile().then((bytes) {
    Share.file('Share via:', imagePath,
        bytes.buffer.asUint8List(), 'image/png');
  });
        */}
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/esys_flutter_share 
In your code, you already have `bytes.buffer.asUint8List()`, so you can directly use it

```
await Share.file('esys image', 'esys.jpg', bytes.buffer.asUint8List(), 'image/jpg', text: 'My optional text.');
```